Coriolis force question about the velocity vector decomposition
I am continuing this question to this one as a new one in order to not post to many questions under one title.
On the wiki page about Coriolis force there is a picture to help demonstrate the concept:

The blue dot located at the most bottom point is the thrower.
The non-inertial reference frame (left) shows the ball curving to the right, due to the Coriolis force. The thrower is here the observer.
In the inertial reference frame, some other observer howering above the carousel, sees the ball follow a straight path until it reaches the center of the carousel.
I will draw a picture:

In my picture, the red curve is the path that the thrower will see.
My question:
I am interested when we are some looking the carousel from up and we are stationary.
I am interested why will the observer howering above the ground (say some drone) see the ball go to the centre of the rotation (as shown in the right wikipedia picture), if the ball (and the thrower) have before the throw some tangential velocity component (the horizontal green vector) and when the thrower throws it he adds the velocity component to the y axis, but still the resultant velocity vector should be the green vector $\mathbf v_{res}$ in my picture, and is pointing to some 45 degrees and not directly to the centre. Will the ball go straight to the centre or will it go like that green vector?
If when rotating, there is always some horizontal green vector component, is it possible to ever actually hit the center of the carousel?
See minute 1:23 in this video.

Corrected picture:


One inaccuracy in the diagram you have drawn that I didn't notice in our discussion on the previous post: the velocity vector you marked in orange $\vec{v}$ is the one measured by the outside, non-rotating observer. Therefore it is in fact not correct to use it in the Coriolis force formula, because this requires the velocity of the object in the rotating frame. In the rotating frame, the velocity vector will be tangent to the red trajectory.

I added the corrected picture for where the thrower is rotating and he throws the ball straight to the center.

 Overview & intuition 
The answer is yes, it is possible to hit the center. It turns out that all the thrower on the carousel needs to do is to make sure that the initial tangential velocity he gives the ball is exactly equal and opposite to the tangential velocity an inertial observer sees him rotating with. So, if the inertial observer is seeing him rotating with tangential velocity $\omega r$, he needs to throw the ball tangentially with velocity $-\omega r$.
It turns out that it doesn't matter at all with what perpendicular speed he throws: as long as we're assuming "ideal" conditions (no air drag, gravity, friction, etc.), any perpendicular component to the ball's velocity in the direction of the center, will cause the ball to eventually hit the center.
 The algebra 
In a uniformly rotating frame, any object is subject to two fictitious forces: the Coriolis force and the centrifugal force. Since our ball is not experiencing any other forces, the mass cancels from both sides and the equation for the acceleration in the rotating frame is:
$$ \boldsymbol{\vec{a}} = -2\boldsymbol{\vec\omega} \times \boldsymbol{\vec{v}} - \boldsymbol{\vec{\omega}}\times(\boldsymbol{\vec{\omega}}\times\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}) $$
With $\boldsymbol{\vec\omega} = \omega \boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$ and $\omega > 0$, so we assume that the rotation relative to the ground is counterclockwise.
This is a differential equation with $\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}(t)$ being the function we want to solve for:
$$ \boldsymbol{\ddot{\vec{r}}} = -2\boldsymbol{\vec\omega} \times \boldsymbol{\dot{\vec{r}}} - \boldsymbol{\vec{\omega}}\times(\boldsymbol{\vec{\omega}}\times\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}) $$
I found that it is easiest for me in this case to work in Cartesian coordinates. In several quite straightforward steps, we get the following system of coupled differential equations for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$:
\begin{align*}
 \ddot{x}&= 2\omega\dot{y} + \omega^2 x\\ 
\ddot{y} &= -2\omega\dot{x}+\omega^2 y
\end{align*}
We're throwing the ball from the "south", like in your diagram. So for a carousel of radius $R$ the initial conditions for the position are:  $x(0)=0,\  y(0)=-R$.
For the initial velocity, we put $\dot{x}(0)=\mathrm{V_{0x}},\  \dot{y}(0)=\mathrm{V_{0y}}$, meaning for now we take the throw to be with any initial velocity $\mathrm{V_0} =\sqrt{\mathrm{V_{0x}}^2+ \mathrm{V_{0y}}^2}$.
The solution under these conditions is:
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \left( \omega R t + \mathrm{V_{0x}}t \right)\cos(\omega t)  +  \left(\mathrm{V_{0y}}t-R\right)\sin(\omega t)\\
y(t) &= \left(\mathrm{V_{0y}}t-R\right)\cos(\omega t)-\left(\omega R t + \mathrm{V_{0x}}t\right)\sin(\omega t)
\end{align*}
Our goal is to hit the center, which means $x(t)=y(t)=0$ for some $t$. So now, it is time to check our intuitive explanation: is it indeed correct that we will always hit the center when the tangential velocity we throw with is:
$$ \mathrm{V_{0x}} = -\omega R $$
We check, by substituting this into the equations of motion we found:
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \require{cancel}\cancelto{0}{\left( \omega R t - \omega R t \right)}\cos(\omega t)  +  \left(\mathrm{V_{0y}}t-R\right)\sin(\omega t)
\\ &=  \left(\mathrm{V_{0y}}t-R\right)\sin(\omega t)\\\\
y(t) &= \left(\mathrm{V_{0y}}t-R\right)\cos(\omega t)-\cancelto{0}{\left(\omega R t - \omega R t\right)}\sin(\omega t)
\\ &= \left(\mathrm{V_{0y}}t-R\right)\cos(\omega t)
\end{align*}
From this, we immediately observe that $x(t)=y(t)=0$ when:
$$ t = \frac{R}{\mathrm{V_{0y}}} $$
We see then that the effect of throwing with a greater $\mathrm{V_{0y}}$ will be only to cause the ball to hit the center earlier than with a smaller $\mathrm{V_{0y}}$, but as promised, any $\mathrm{V_{0y}}>0$ will cause the ball to hit the center within some finite amount of time.
 Plotting the trajectory 
Here are a few plots I made in Geogebra, to show various trajectories the ball can take from the perspective of the rotating frame. The only thing I varied was $\mathrm{V_{0y}}$, and I used the equations of motion and the condition $ \mathrm{V_{0x}} = -\omega R $ to generate the plots:

As you can see, one can get some interesting trajectory shapes by varying $\mathrm{V_{0y}}$.
The interesting thing to recall is, that all such trajectories correspond to straight lines for the outside, inertial observer on the ground (or indeed the drone hovering above the carousel). The only difference between these trajectories for the inertial observer, will be the speed that the ball is travelling with.
You can also experiment with this Geogebra plot here, it can be made to be a lot nicer and easier to use, but perhaps you'll find it helpful.
(Note that $ \mathrm{V_{0x}}$ is "locked in" currently, you can change that via the Algebra view, to see what happens when it has other values).

 Addendum - an easier way to obtain the equations of motion 
If we rearrange the equations of motion we obtained for the ball (the general ones, with any initial $\mathrm{V_{0x}}$ and $\mathrm{V_{0y}}$) as follows:
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \cos(\omega t)\left( \omega R t + \mathrm{V_{0x}}t \right)  +  \sin(\omega t)\left(-R+\mathrm{V_{0y}}t\right)\\
y(t) &= -\sin(\omega t)\left(\omega R t + \mathrm{V_{0x}}t\right)+\cos(\omega t)\left(-R+\mathrm{V_{0y}}t\right)
\end{align*}
We notice that we can put them into matrix form:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  \cos(\omega t) & \sin(\omega t) \\ 
-\sin(\omega t) & \cos(\omega t) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\omega R t + \mathrm{V_{0x}}t\\  -R+\mathrm{V_{0y}}t \end{pmatrix} $$
So that we can see, we could also obtain the equations of motion of the ball in the rotating frame, by transforming the position vector that corrsponds to the motion in the inertial frame:
$$ \boldsymbol{\vec{r}}_{\text{inertial}} = \begin{pmatrix} \omega R t + \mathrm{V_{0x}}t\\  -R+\mathrm{V_{0y}}t \end{pmatrix} $$
to the uniformly rotating frame, via the above matrix. As you can see the $x$ and $y$ components in the inertial frame, correspond to our initial conditions, since at $t=0$ the ball's velocity is tangent to the $x$ axis in the inertial frame, its motion along $x$ in this frame is given by the sum of the tangential velocity $\omega R$ and the initial velocity imparted by the thrower $\mathrm{V_{0x}}$:
$$ x(t)_{\text{inertial}} = \left(\omega R  + \mathrm{V_{0x}}\right)t $$
Similarly, because we have required $y(0)=-R$, $x(0)=0$, this is true in both frames (they always have to agree on the distance from the origin). So that the motion along $y$ in the inertial frame is given by:
$$ y(t)_{\text{inertial}} = -R+\mathrm{V_{0y}}t $$
So, we could sidestep the (relatively) complicated differential equations by using this approach. However, since your question was framed in terms of the Coriolis force, I think it is somewhat illuminating here to see how the same equations of motion are obtained by starting from the fictitious forces, which is why I thought it would be better not to edit out the more complicated derivation given above.
